# Check if a field has been modified with angular 6 and firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form for editing a user details, where it should check if the user has make modification if not then don't make changes.
Currently am using `if` to check which is working but I still feel is not effective way for this, because I have multiple fields which have to check each of them which makes the code repetitive and huge.

```
    if (f.value.first_name) {
        this.user.firstName = f.value.first_name;
    }
```

I have tried using elvis operator but it's not working for me

```
this.user.firstName ?  this.user.firstName :f.value.first_name;
```

Is there any other effective way to do this?

Comment: If your code works and you're just asking for ways to make it more efficient, I recommend asking this on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each form controls and check if they are `dirty` (modified).

```
Object.keys(f.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
        if (f.get(key).dirty) {
            this.user[key] = f.get(key).value
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep a copy of the original object and then do this:

```
get isDirty(): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(this.originalProduct) !== JSON.stringify(this.currentProduct);
}
```

I `stringify` the copy of the original product (before edits) and the current product and compare them. I assume if they are not equal that something changed.

There are some caveats to this approach, especially if your object structure is complex as there *may* be cases that stringify does not create the strings exactly the same. But I have not run into this case.

Comment: Will test this looks promising :)